Not supported wheel on platform
I am trying to install zeroc-ice in a kubernetes pod that is running the image ghcr.io/home-assistant/raspberrypi4-homeassistant:2022.9.5. For this you first need to access the container and install the following packages:
apk add build-base
apk add openssl-dev
apk add bzip2-dev

And then you can install zeroc-ice with:
pip install zeroc-ice
This generates a whl file that i can copy into the host machine, so the next time i launch the pod i dont need to do these steps and i only need to install using the whl file. Having the wheel file generated directly from the image means that i have the correct whl for the next times.
The problem is that when i try to install using the wheel i get the next error:
bash-5.1# pip install zeroc_ice-3.7.10-cp310-cp310-linux_aarch64.whl 
ERROR: zeroc_ice-3.7.10-cp310-cp310-linux_aarch64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.


The thing is that this works on a docker container with the image homeassistant/home-assistant:2022.9.5 (obviously this generates a different wheel). Now i need it to work on kubernetes with the image ghcr.io/home-assistant/raspberrypi4-homeassistant:2022.9.5.
I tried the following steps:

Get into the kubernetes pod
Install zeroc-ice with the commands previously mentioned (this does not give any error, and i can import Ice without problems)
I copy the generated wheel into the host machine to use it later as i said.
Now, without restarting the pod or anything like that, i tried to re-install ice using the wheel with the command pip install <path to the wheel>, but this gives the same error:

bash-5.1# pip install zeroc_ice-3.7.10-cp310-cp310-linux_aarch64.whl 
ERROR: zeroc_ice-3.7.10-cp310-cp310-linux_aarch64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.


This discards the possibility of having a dependency with the commands previously mentioned.
This does not make any sense to me so any help or ideas would be helpful.

Your wheel is for cp310-linux_aarch64: Python 3.10, OS: Linux, Processor: ARM64. If you have something different in another container you need to generate a different wheel. Most probably Python version is different. Check with pip --version .

You should also check the architecture of your userland with something like file /bin/bash. For some reason, Raspberry Pi distributions LOVE it to ship an armv7 userland for an arm64 kernel.

@phd The thing is that i have generated the wheel in the "same" container i want to use it later. Im generating the wheel in ghcr.io/home-assistant/raspberrypi4-homeassistant:2022.9.5 but i will have to do this only once. The next times i create the container it will automatically install the package using the wheel. As you can see the versions cant be different since it is generated in the container itself.

@Siguza Checking what you mention gives me the next info:

Host machine: /bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, BuildID[sha1]=198ac6b0cc01bf774c5746a36a6fd31dead9bda5, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, stripped
Container: /bin/bash: ELF 32-bit LSB pie executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-armhf.so.1, stripped

The wheel generated in the container is zeroc_ice-3.7.10-cp310-cp310-linux_aarch64.whl, i dont really understand all this info, is there a problem here?

@DanielEspinar yep, that's precisely what I was referring to: the binaries inside your container are 32-bit. I don't know anything about "zeroc_ice" or "wheels", but pip is likely rejecting it because it has the wrong architecture.

I have realized that the container generates the wheel with a wrong tag. The content of the wheel is generated properly so changing the name to a supported tag fixes it.
